# Load Barcode Generator Library to Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

Normally I always install some extension by using composer , but now I need to use Barcode Generator library 
http://www.barcodebakery.com/en

In order to use their library I need to

```
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');
```

but I don't know what is the best practice to do it with yii2
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in [this doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html)

> Yii relies on the class autoloading mechanism to locate and include
>   all required class files. It provides a high-performance class
>   autoloader that is compliant with the PSR-4 standard. The autoloader
>   is installed when you include the Yii.php file.

Then for your requirement the best pratice you are looking for is described in the doc mentioned above.